Beamerposter Formatting/Display Issues
I'm trying to make a research poster (landscape style) with 3 columns of material. The problem is the body of the poster gets written on the top center of the page. I have to include more columns before the first column shifts to the left, and even then it doesn't shift the way I want it to.
example:
\documentclass[final, compress]{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation = landscape]{beamerposter}

\setlength{\paperwidth}{36in} 
\setlength{\paperheight}{22.7in}

\begin{document}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.25\paperwidth}
    content...
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{document}

Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, starting with \documentclass and ending with \end{document}, instead of a code snippet.

Beamer columns essentially work like
\hfill +  first column + \hfill + second column + \hfill + ...
This means that if you only have one column it will be centred. If you don't like this, you could use minipages instead.

Some other comments:

you need to place all your content in a frame. Otherwise the page geometry isn't correctly set up
by default, columns will have different margins than normal text. If you want to align the columns with the surrounding text, use the onlytextwidth option

\documentclass[final, compress]{beamer}
\usepackage[
  orientation=landscape,
  scale=0.9,
  size=custom,
  width=91.44,
  height=57.658
]{beamerposter}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{0.33\paperwidth}
    content...
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.33\paperwidth}
    content...
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.33\paperwidth}
    content...
    \end{column}        
\end{columns}

\begin{minipage}{.25\textwidth}
content...
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

